# How to change Files tab SharePoint site link in Teams?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, hyperlink, microsoft-teams

I want to change SharePoint site link associated with Files tab of team in Microsoft teams. Can this is possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer to your question is it is **not possible**.

> When a new channel is created within an existing team, a document library is created within the Office 365 Group the team is associated with. This document library is "pinned" to the channel as a tab called Files. This allows you to interact with the files in the document library directly within Teams without having to leave the application.

**Source**: [Microsoft Teams: Use an Existing SharePoint Library](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/skypehybridguy/2017/10/28/microsoft-teams-use-an-existing-sharepoint-library/).

But if you want to use an existing document library from your SharePoint site then it's possible to connect that library to the channel in Microsoft Teams.

You can **Add a tab** or **Add cloud storage** to your channel. Check "What if I want to use an existing document library?" section given in above link to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

So, for me, I use the 'link to a Website", copy in for instance a different Sharepoint URL, type in the title for the tab, and it works perfectly and takes you directly to the other Sharepoint site not created when creating a new Channel in Teams O365 !  As others have said, waste of time, cannot do it, if try using the create tab options for Docs or for Sharepoint.